# POST Request in API Testing using ROBOT Framework

Tags: api, unit-testing, robotframework

Hi All I want to POST the below format as input in ROBOT Framework.

```
{
    "Description": "School",
    "Details": [
    {
      "name": "Test1",
      "Surname": "XYZ"
    },
    {
      "name1": "Test2",
      "Surname2": "ABC"
    }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting the below error

```
body={"Error":"module 'jsonschema._utils' has no attribute 'types_msg'"}
```

Below is my code for the same

```
${tag_1} =  create dictionary        name="Test1"     value"XYZ"
      ${tag_2} =  create dictionary        name="Test2"     value"ABC"
      ${body} =  create list        Description="School"      Details=[$tag_1,$tag_2]
      ${header}=  create dictionary   Authorization=%{TEMP_TOKEN}   content-Type=application/json
     ${create_student}=  post On Session  ABCDE    /input   json=${body}     headers=${header}       expected_status=200
```

Comment: You do not need quotes around strings. `name=Test1` is enough and your quotes might cause issues later.

Comment: What is value"XYZ"? it is not valid as a dictionary key/value pair and doesn't match your json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like there are a few issues - Mainly, you're trying to store the json in an array, not an object and you're not converting to JSON.

There was also the double quotes around the key values and invalid key/value for value"XYX" and value"ABC" which also doesn't match your example as it should be "Surname"

Some example changes below:

```
# Name and Surname Objects - Updated to remove double quotes and match the provided json with "Surname" instead of "value"
${tag_1}  Create Dictionary  name=Test1  Surname=XYZ
${tag_2}  Create Dictionary  name=Test2  Surname=ABC

# Details List / Json Array
@{details}  Create List  ${tag_1}  ${tag_2}

# Body - Fixed so it's an object not an array
&{body}  Create Dictionary  
...      Description=School
...      Details=${details}

# Convert the body to JSON
${body}  Evaluate  json.dumps(${body})  json
```

Output:

```
{"Description": "School", "Details": [{"name": "Test1", "Surname": "XYZ"}, {"name": "Test2", "Surname": "ABC"}]}
```